# warning: unused variable

Tags: c, warnings

see in one code i have written

```
void my_function()
{
INT32 i;    /* Variable for iteration */ 
/* If system is little-endian, store bytes in array as reverse order */
#ifdef LITTLE   
   {    
    // i m using i for operating one loop 
   }
#endif

 /* If the system is big-endian, store bytes in array as forward order */
#ifdef  BIG 
   {
   // using i for loop
   }
#endif
return;
 }
```

by compiling this code with -Wall flag it shows

```
 warning: unused variable ‘i’
```

why?
how can i remove this?

Comment: Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4) (GCC)

Comment: Despite missing the two #endif. Could it be that neither LITTLE nor BIG is defined? Or that you are using a for(int i...) loop, effectively declaring i a second time?

Comment: @ Hunter McMillen in for loop

Comment: @ Darcara  sory i have already written two #endif still i m getting this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey i got the answer...

see BIG & LITTLE are preposser flag & they are given at compile time.
when i was compiling my project with make file i was giving this flag at compile time but while testing each individual file i was compiling like

```
gcc -Wall -c filename.c
```

This was comming because i havent given any flag so compiler going to neglet that much portion of code & i was getting warning.

```
gcc -Wall -c -LITTLE filename.c
```

works perfectly...

Answer (score 4):

Put the declaration of `i` just inside the `{}` where you actually use it. Even better if you have C99, declare the loop variable inside the `for(int i = 0, i < bound; ++i)`

Answer (score 1):

By defining either `LITTLE` or `BIG`. I doubt many compilers give that warning for this code when one of those symbols are defined. If you still have the warning, then you might change the second `#ifdef` to an `#else`.

I don't see any `#endif` anywhere -- presumably in the real code, those appear.

Comment: sory i have already written two #endif still i m getting this

Comment: So have you actually defined LITTLE or BIG somewhere?

Comment: i am giving this flag at compile time

Answer (score 1):

You need to define either BIG or LITTLE (as mentioned elsewhere).

In order to stop this happening again in the future, you can raise a specific compile-time error using the following:

```
#if !defined LITTLE && !defined BIG
#error You haven't defined one of your macro names
#endif
```

Alternatively, you could include `i` only when using either code block by surrounding it with `#if defined` as well:

```
#if defined LITTLE || defined BIG
INT32 i;
#endif
```

In both cases, note the keyword to use is `#if` not `#ifdef` or `#ifndef`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to declare the iteration number. Just do it in your for statement.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
  // insert loop code here
```

}